# Como alinhar corretamente uma galeria de itens com flexbox?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Estou começando a usar CSS flex, e percebi que quando centralizamos um container, parece que os elementos dentro do container parecem ficar centralizados, porém se eu alinho ele para direita, o container perde a centralização:

Alinhado à esquerda (tenho o problema com um espaço grande na direita):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alinhando ao centro, tenho um problema com os elementos centralizados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    max-width: 136px;
    flex: 1 0 136px;
    margin: 0 5px 20px;
}
```

Este é o [exemplo acima](http://jsfiddle.net/148ms7db/).
E [não é bem isso](http://jsfiddle.net/puz219/7Hq2E/) que quero.

Usando float, eu ainda conseguia fazer um [alinhamento na tela](http://jsfiddle.net/rc5x8pu1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um wrapper interno,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: calc(146px * 3)
}

.item {
  max-width: 136px;
  flex: 1 0 136px;
  margin: 0 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/136">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/136">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/136">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/136">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#obs: você pode remover o calc do css, foi somente para exibição, o flex fará isso automático

#edit: container alinhado no centro, ainda pode remover o calc do `.container-inner` irá funcionar do mesmo modo, o conceito continua sendo o mesmo.. espero ter ajudado

Comment: Meu mas a sua resposta ficou do jeito que ele NÃO quer, com o último item no centro...

Comment: Pois é, então esse é o problema...

Comment: @Ruansenadev, coloquei que sua resposta está certa, foi exatamente assim que eu fiz e deu certo, mas acabei chegando na solução sozinho, de qualquer forma, valeu!